# What's the meaning of dword_XXXX and offset dword_XXXX in IDA?

Tags: ida, x86, nasm

Consider the following code:

In C++:

```
SomeClass* globalPointer; // we don't know what it points to, but it's not null a pointer, it's initialized

void someFunction()
{
  globalPointer->someVirtualFunction();
}
```

In IDA (inside `someFunction`):

```
mov     ecx, dword_XXXX ; ecx = globalPointer
mov     eax, [ecx] ; eax = vtable
jmp     dword ptr [eax+30h] ; call vtable[0x30]
```

The meaning of `dword_XXXX` is just a pointer value. I tried to check it this way:

```
printf("Address of pointer = %p, pointer's value = %p\n", &otherPointer, otherPointer);
```

And I got:

```
push dword_XXXX ; otherPointer
push offset dword_XXXX ; &otherPointer
push offset format ; "Address of pointer = %p, pointer's value = %p\n"

call printf
```

Thus `dword_XXXX` seems to be a pointer's value and `offset dword_XXXX` seems to be an address of the pointer.

However, I noticed another code (which can be expressed the same as the c++ function I provided above):

```
SomeClass2* globalPointer2;

void someFunction2()
{
  globalPointer2->someVirtualFunction2();
}
```

And IDA surprisingly gave me (inside `someFunction2`):

```
mov eax, dword_XXXX ; eax = globalPointer2
mov ecx, offset dword_XXXX ; ecx = &globalPointer2
jmp dword ptr [eax+5Ch] ; call [globalPointer2+0x5C] with &globalPointer2 as this?? It should be call vtable[0x5C]
```

I checked the values and found out that IDA somehow "changes" the meaning of `dword_XXXX`, in this case it actually was:

```
mov eax, dword_XXXX ; eax = vtable
mov ecx, offset dword_XXXX ; ecx = globalPointer2
jmp dword ptr [eax+5Ch] ; call vtable[0x5C]
```

Why the meaning of `dword_XXXX` was different in the second case? In the first case it was just `pointer`, but in the second case it was `*pointer`.

And the meaning of `offset dword_XXXX` in the first case was `&pointer` and in the second case was `pointer`.

I'm sorry if something is unclear, I really tried to simplify that as much as possible.

Comment: Remove your answer from the question and add it as an answer. You can post answers to your own questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured out what's going on.

The opcodes for the printing were (assuming `dword_AAAAAAAA` instead of general `dword_XXXX`):

```
FF 35 AA AA AA AA    push dword_AAAAAAAA; otherPointer
68 AA AA AA AA       push offset dword_AAAAAAAA; &otherPointer
```

Thanks to [this](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) site, I know that the above instructions are equal to:

```
push [0xAAAAAAAA]; push otherPointer
push 0xAAAAAAAA;   push &otherPointer
```

So, in this case, `dword_XXXX` is equal to value of a pointer. However, in the second case (again assuming `dword_AAAAAAAA` instead of general `dword_XXXX`):

```
A1 AA AA AA AA    mov eax, dword_AAAAAAAA ; eax = vtable
B9 AA AA AA AA    mov ecx, offset dword_AAAAAAAA ; ecx = globalPointer2
```

And it's equal to:

```
mov eax, [0xAAAAAAAA] ; eax = vtable
mov ecx, 0xAAAAAAAA ; ecx = globalPointer2
```

Thus in this case `dword_XXXX` is equal to `*pointer` rather than `pointer`.

Therefore I think the answer is: it depends. We need to understand what `dword_XXXX` means - it can be a pointer, an address of the pointer, or even pointer to pointer to pointer, and so on. But IDA gives us a hint: `offset dword_XXXX` means a raw value of whatever `dword_XXXX` is and `dword_XXXX` gives a dereferenced value of it.